# Record audio from both sides of the skype call in nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-api, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

I am writing a node.js program for transcribing skype calls using Google speech api, for that I am easily able to read microphone input but not able to read what the other person is speaking. Is there a way in  which this can be done using node.js.

Comment: Which package you're using? and I assume you are able to read your voice and unable to read the caller's voice right? (Correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: I am using binaryjs and its able to read my voice, but cant record the caller's voice.